# It’s time to get back on course

Tags: discussion

I’ve noticed a growing obsession with numbers on Raspberry Pi these past few months. *The thing is, watching stats isn’t your job.* **Your job is to create the very best body of Raspberry Pi knowledge on the internet, one high quality question and answer at a time.**

This site has a lot going for it. If you keep up like you have been, I’m confident you’ll be graduating soon enough. However, [trying to game the numbers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) is counterproductive. **Don’t do it.**

The drive to graduate makes sense, but a single minded obsession with numbers leads a community to take their focus off of quality. As long as the content on Raspberry Pi is making the internet a better place, we’re okay with letting it take as long as it takes. This is why we’ve [begun to approach the beta period](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/) as though a site might be there for quite awhile, and that’s completely fine.

The community team is not obsessing over Raspberry Pi’s numbers. Neither should you.

Comment: Well said. The pro-tem mods echo your views :)

Comment: Thank you, I began to feel like I was the only one beating that drum.

Comment: Glad to hear it. :)

Comment: @SteveRobillard I think you've done a great job pointing this out. I gotta kinda embarrassedly admit that I was kinda behind some of the **numbers/stats up** push. I have since been corrected, and I'm glad Steve has been *beating that drum* as well as Ana for pointing this out clearly!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Your enthusiasm is admirable, please don't change that. Just make sure its directed towards the things that really make a difference.

Comment: Yea fantastic, at last we can close and move allot of these questions that are really distantly associated with the Pi. It has become quite annoying looking at question that really belong somewhere else but are her just because they have the word `Pi` in the them.